# Ajax request between subdomains with different ftp

Tags: php, ajax, linux, file-upload, cross-domain

I have 2 subdomains,which are hosted on same server. Each have separate ftp login. How can i make ajax request from one subdomain to another. My ultimate aim is to upload image from one subdomain to another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browsers do not provide a Javascript FTP API, as far as I know. But even if they did, what exactly do you mean by making an AJAX request from one FTP subdomain to another?

Comment: @Sverri M.Olsen: yes, i mean the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to add the following headers at the beginning of your upload script

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.yourdomain.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true');
```

This will allow you to make cross-domain requests